# Printing formatted bash comment values before execution

Tags: bash

I was wondering if there was a way to print formatted comments that already exist within a bash file before the file is executed. I tried the "strings" command on Linux but the comments are not formatted and are still in bash.

Comment: `grep ^# file`?

Comment: @alecxs That does not seem to work either

Comment: ...depending on input and expectations (which is guesswork so far)

Comment: I guess a better way to format this question would be how can display the comments in a bash file while also executing the bash formatting "commands". This way the comments are in normal text format.

Comment: What "formatting commands" are you talking about?

Comment: An example (small input script & expected formatted output) would help clarify what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack with `trap` but might help:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'p=$(($LINENO-1)); sed -n "${p}{ /^\s*#/p }" $0' DEBUG

function fun {
  trap 'p=$(($LINENO-1)); sed -n "${p}{ /^\s*#/p }" $0' DEBUG
  # now in a function
  echo "in a function"
}

# This is a comment before pwd
pwd

fun

# And this is a comment before bar
echo "bar"
echo "Hello world without comment"
```

Output:

```
# This is a comment before pwd
/tmp
  # now in a function
in a function
# And this is a comment before bar
bar
Hello world without comment
```

Answer (score 2):

## Script

I don't know any program to do it, but the best script I can come up with gets it almost right:

```
cat file.sh \
    | sed \
        -e "s/^\([^\"'#]*\(\(\"[^\"]*\"\)\|\('[^']*'\)\)\)*//g" \
    | sed \
        -e "/^[^'#]*'[^']*$/d" \
        -e '/^[^"#]*"[^"]*$/d' \
    | grep -o \
        -e '^#.*' \
        -e '[[:space:]]#.*' \
    | sed \
        -e 's/^ //'
```

## Example

Example file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# comment 1
# comment #2
echo x # comment 3
echo y # comment #4
echo '# a'
echo '# b' # comment 5
echo '# c' # comment #6
echo "# a"
echo "# b" # comment 7
echo "# c" # comment #8
echo 'hello "d"'
echo 'hello "# e"'
echo 'hello "f"' # comment 9
echo 'hello "# g"' # comment 10
echo "hello 'h'"
echo "hello '# i'"
echo "hello 'j'" # comment 11
echo "hello '# k'" # comment 12
echo '\#'
echo "\#"
echo '\#' # comment 13
echo "\#" # comment 14
       # comment 15
echo $(echo l # comment 16
# comment 17
)
echo "'" # comment 18
echo '"' # comment 19
echo "'" "'" # comment 20
echo '"' '"' # comment 21
echo "'" ' #' " #" "''" # comment 22
echo '"' ' #' " #" '""' # comment 23
echo '"' "'" '"' "'" '"' "'" # comment 24
echo '"' "'" '"' "'" '"' "'" # comment '25'
echo '"' "'" '"' "'" '"' "'" # comment '26
echo '"' "'" '"' "'" '"' "'" # comment 27'
echo 'm # noncomment 1001
# noncomment 1002'
# comment 28 '
echo "m # noncomment 1003
# noncomment 1004"
# comment 29 "
echo '' ' #' " #" 'm # noncomment 1005
# noncomment 1006'
echo '' ' #' " #" "m # noncomment 1007
# noncomment 1008"
\# noncomment 1009
echo x \# noncomment 1010
echo x# noncomment 1011
echo $#
echo $# # comment 30
echo ${#HOME}
echo ${#HOME} # comment 31
```

Output:

```
#!/bin/bash
# comment 1
# comment #2
# comment 3
# comment #4
# comment 5
# comment #6
# comment 7
# comment #8
# comment 9
# comment 10
# comment 11
# comment 12
# comment 13
# comment 14
# comment 15
# comment 16
# comment 17
# comment 18
# comment 19
# comment 20
# comment 21
# comment 22
# comment 23
# comment 24
# comment '25'
# comment '26
# comment 27'
# noncomment 1002'
# comment 28 '
# noncomment 1004"
# comment 29 "
# noncomment 1006'
# noncomment 1008"
# comment 30
# comment 31
```

Note that some noncomments are seen as comments due to multiline strings. There's probably a way to get sed to understand it, but that would make this complicated script even more complicated.

## Explanation

The first `sed -e "s/^\([^\"'#]*\(\(\"[^\"]*\"\)\|\('[^']*'\)\)\)*//g"` is meant to remove strings. Strings are a problem because they can contain `#`. The pattern `s/regex//g` removes everything that matches the regex. The regex we want is `^(non-comment-non-string)(double-quoted-string|single-quoted-string)*`.  The regex `regex1\|regex2` matches either of the inner regular expressions.

`^\([^\"'#]*...\)` starts at the beginning of the line and skips everything that's not a string or a comment. `\(\"[^\"]*\"\)` and `\('[^']*'\)\)` remove double-quoted and single-quoted strings, respectively.

The second sed has `-e "/^[^'#]*'[^']*$/d"` and `-e '/^[^"#]*"[^"]*$/d'`, which delete lines that start a string before a comment, but don't end it. Since the previous steps removed all the single-line strings, it's enough to do it by looking for lines with a only one single- or double-quote.

Then, we remove everything that can't contain a comment, by grepping '^#.*' and `'[[:space:]]#.*'`. `-o` also tells grep to only print the matching part, leaving out the non-comment part.

Last, because `'[[:space:]]#.*'` starts with whitespace, we manually remove it with `sed -e 's/^ //'`.

Comment: This seems like as close as you can get without an actual parser... I think it can't deal with $# right now though, right?

Comment: Nice catch! it couldn't deal with anything uses `#` as part of actual bash syntax - I edited the answer with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is a comment

# this display all comments
# $0 is script file name
grep ^# "$0"

sleep 3
echo "Hello World"

# end of file
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.